# Java worker threads, terminating condition

Tags: java, multithreading

I have three worker threads from main thread. Main thread puts objects into **BlockingQueue**. if queue does not have enough data, lets say only one object. Other two threads keep waiting state. How to i signal those other two waiting threads (***because of call to queue.take()***) to terminate?

one way to do this would be pass last dirty object on queue to have other stale threads to read and terminate. Is there any other elegant solution available?

```
public void run() {
if (log.isInfoEnabled()) {
    log.info("Entering method 'run' " + this.getName());
}
try {
    while (!noMoreData || !queue.isEmpty()) {
        String data = queue.take();
        ...
        ...
        doSomething();
    }
    if (log.isInfoEnabled()) {
        log.info("noMoreData =" + noMoreData + ", queue empty=" + queue.isEmpty() + "....Terminating thread..." + this.getName());
    }
} catch (InterruptedException ie) {
    log.error(ie);
} finally {
    //DONE SIGNAL
    doneSignal.countDown();
    log.info(this.getName() + " finished.");
}
}
```

Comment: Can you describe why you would like to prematurely end this thread while its blocking on the queue? Usually you'd want to allow the thread to die normally, so I'm just curious about your scenario.

Comment: Queueing up a 'poison pill' termination-request object is a fairly common technique - it's elegant enough, so why use anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an ExecutorService using your configured queue (size and datastructure).

You then have a shutdown message (Runnable) that you submit to the executorservice which calls  #shutdown(). Just submit that message last on the queue.

This method is very scalable  because you can replace the executorservice wih a true message queue.

Comment: Using Future it is easier to detect and shutdown

Answer (score 1):

Would Thread.interrupt() suit your needs?  If you keep references to the three threads, you can interrupt the other two, causing the take() method to throw InterruptedException.

Comment: Yes, interrupt each consuming thread.  It looks like the run method is already written so it will terminate itself cleanly when interrupted, and the purpose of an interrupt is pretty much to signal a thread that it should clean up and terminate itself.